# Where to enable post publishing for incoming email to list SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, incoming-email

In SP 2007 when I enable incoming email to list I had the following option:

> **Post Publishing**
>
> Choose whether posts received by e-mail are
>   published immediately or saved as drafts.
>
> Accept all emails as draft?
>
> - Save all posts received by e-mail as drafts
> - Publish posts received by e-mail if users have permission

I had content approval checked in the list.

In SP 2010 I can't find that option to save it has a draft first before publishing.

Comment: Has incoming email been configured in the new 2010 instance?

Comment: Not yet.If i configure that would it show up.
It would be nice if you can confirm that.
Chrs

Comment: Yes, that information does not appear unless incoming email is configured.